# Using Nulled Wordpress Themes, Does it reduce " Loading Speed" or " Security" Of the Website?

Tags: wordpress, security, themes, wordpress-theming

I am using a nulled wordpress theme named "Toranj".
The Security of the site and the loading speed of it is so important to me.
however, i heared that, using nulled theme, will cause some problems such as reduction in loading speed and the security!
is it right? 
and if its right, how to solve it? 
thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what a "nulled theme" is. Some WordPress themes contain hidden ads or malware.

Answer (score 4):

A nulled theme is a *pirated* theme oftenly filled with backdoor and etc. 
Solved by BUYING and paying the people who made the theme.

Note that even when you buy wordpress/plugins you have to do a review of the code to know if it is really have serious performance issues or security issues..

Comment: Yes. Arash, there are lots of very good free themes available at [the WordPress site](https://wordpress.org/themes/). If you need a particular "premium" theme like Toranj, just buy it! Toranj costs less than $60. If you use a pirated theme, you put both your own web site _and_ _all_ _of_ _your_ _users_ at risk! And if your users get hacked because of your site, then it will end up on all kinds of blacklistings. So even if you don't care about the developers who put time and effort into the theme, stay away from the pirated version for your own sake...

Answer (score -1):

Nulled is a term referred to removing license check from a software. Here , we are talking about themes and plugins , that is php scripts.Nulled Theme is the premium theme which is modified in such a way so that it cannot check whether the license is genuine or not , or it may be modified in such a way that when it check its license , it will always return true , so the theme license is genuine and users can use it premium features. Same concept is applied to Nulled Plugin.

Using Nulled Theme can cause you many problems like

- Slow down website speed
- Can Make Your Site Load Other's Ads
- Can Remove You From Site's Administrator !

So don't use nulled scripts or nulled theme/plugin

Source : [Why To Not Use Nulled Scripts](https://www.narendradwivedi.org/2021/01/what-is-nulled-script.html)